# Some keys stop working in Visual Studio 2008 IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard

I use Windows 7 64-bit with 4 GB RAM to run a Windows Virtual PC Guest with Windows 2008 Server, Visual Studio 2008 SP1/Resharper 4.5 and SQL Server 2008. The guest has 2 GB RAM allocated.

Sometimes certain keys stop working in the VS IDE, most often the arrow keys, backspace and enter. The keys still works in Windows and other applications. Restarting VS seems to be the only solution. I've read some suggestions about not using the auto-hide toolbars/windows, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yeah, I've had that happen with the Express Edition (C#) as well. Restarting the IDE was the only thing that worked for me too. I'm going to keep an eye on this post in case someone else has a better solution.

Comment: @Jonas I think ReSharper is the culprit, because I get this problem sometimes with ReSharper 5 in Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 RC. Try without ReSharper and see if the problem disappears. (Doesn't explain @Frust's problem though.)

Comment: I've had this happen - mostly the enter key - VS 2008, with or without SP1, no ReSharper. That's with the TFS Client, which I do like to blame for things, and lousy hardware, which also deserves a lot of blame.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, really annoying. A friend at work showed me a simple fix. Just Press Alt+Enter. I have VS 2010. This corrects the issue every time.

Comment: Thanks ! This trick works for me in VS2010, no needs to close / restart VS again !

Comment: This worked for me too! I've had this problem for years and never found a fix, I can't believe it was so simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do one thing go to your visual studio editor,Under it go to Tools->Import And Export Settings...->Reset All Settings
After resetting it your problem will be solve.

Comment: I just ran into this again in both VS 2012 and 2013, and this was what fixed it. I'd tried the Alt-Enter trick, closing the toolbox, verifying that the VS internationalization setting was set to match Windows, restarting VS, rebooting Windows, none of which worked for me until I reset all settings.

Answer (score 1):

This issue still exists in VS2010 and I ran into it again. Microsoft are aware but still no fix:

> [Backspace and Arrow key not working (MS Connect)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567055/backspace-and-arrow-key-not-working?wa=wsignin1.0)
>
> [Arrow keys stop working in editor (MS Connect)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534869/arrow-keys-stop-working-in-editor?wa=wsignin1.0)